# php rename the uploaded file with extension

Tags: php, file-io

I have a php code as follows:

```
    $titleA = $_POST["title"];

if (in_array($_FILES["file"]["type"], $valid_mime_types)) {
    $destination = "bannerImages/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"];
    move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], $destination); }
```

I would like to change the file name with $titleA variable. But the extension will be the same. basically, filename will become what has been written for title. let me say, original file is first.jpeg second will be second.jpeg.

Comment: What have you already tried? Could you post some samples of things that you have tried, but do not work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hello if i understand you correctly you are having problem extracting extension information. you can always use `pathinfo`

Example

```
$extention = pathinfo("first.jpeg ",PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
$newName = "secound." . $extention ;
var_dump($newName);
```

Output

```
string 'secound.jpg' (length=11)
```

Comment: Ok,

let me say $title = "second";

and my original file is: first.jpg

I would like to make it second.jpeg. title variable will be assigned by user. I am not going to touch extension. Just name.

Comment: Its the same ad demonstrated above .. Just swon you how to extract extension .. it does not mater what the name is you can switch

Answer (score 1):

basically you need extension of a uploaded file,

you have to get extension first, you have file

```
$_FILES["file"]["name"]
```

String position "strpos()" will get the dot point of a file

```
$idx = strpos($_FILES['file']['name'],'.');
```

After dot point you have to get file extension through;

```
$ext = substr($_FILES['file']['name'],$idx);
```

and finally change the file name as you desired,

```
$file_name = $titleA . $ext;
```

Answer (score 0):

When using move_uploaded_file you get to pick the filename, so you can pick anything you want.

When you upload the file, its put into a temporary directory with a temporary name, move_uploaded_file() allows you to move that file and in that you need to set the name of the file as well.

Answer (score 0):

Below is the code how I rename the file extension all from .png to .jpg

```
function replace_extension($filename, $new_extension) {
     $info = pathinfo($filename);
    $newname = $info['filename'] . '.' . $new_extension;
    rename('/home/image/'.$filename, '/home/image/'.$newname);
    return $newname;
}
$dir = '/home/image';
$files = scandir($dir);
//print_r($files);
foreach($files as $key => $file)
{
     echo replace_extension($file, 'jpg');
    echo "<br />";
}
```